# Configuring routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Books controller and I need to configure restful routes for API webservice.I need to set the routes for the below urls

```
books/book_id/search
books/book_id/delete
books/book_id/next
```

How do i do it

Comment: Google for Rails routing, there's an entire document covering all this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to use the HTTP method `GET` for your `search` and `next` APIs, and the HTTP method `DELETE` for your `delete` API, I'd set up the routes like this (also assuming you have a `books` controller with the respective actions) :

```
get 'books/:book_id/search', to: 'books#search'
delete 'books/:book_id/delete', to: 'books#delete'
get 'books/:book_id/next', to: 'books#next'
```

FYI, this is using [non-resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) with a combination of [dynamic segments,](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) [static segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments), and [defaulting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) to a controller named `books`.

Comment: Why do that instead of using the RESTful mechanisms the framework provides?

Comment: Non-resourceful routes can [still be RESTful](http://nih.blogspot.com/2011/07/resourceful-restful-resourceful-routing.html) - it's all about how you handle the request. I used non-resourceful routes because I don't know the exact requirements of the poster; it was the most straightforward way of handling these specific URLs without having to deal with [restricting routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created) and adding additional [member and collection actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to the default resource.